# Ruby, 2 dimensional arrays, make 2d array with size MxN plus change created lines

Tags: ruby, arrays, sequence, user-input, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to learn ruby with solving some problems. Here i take a problem from Pascal.
Here is the exact text:

Ask the user to input two positive integers M and N. Make the 2 dimensional array of integers with size MxN, fill the array with 0. Change all odd lines values to sequence 1,2,3,…,M and even lines values to the M,M-1,M-2,…,1.
 
I read Ruby literature, but have no idea how to start and make 2D array which depends of user input.

So, here is my final code:

```
require 'matrix'
print "Define M: "
m = gets.to_i
print "Define N: "
n = gets.to_i

matrix = Matrix.build(m, n) do |r, c|
  if r.even? and m > c
    c+1
  elsif r.even? 
    0
  else
    m-c
  end
end

print matrix.each_slice(matrix.column_size) {|r| p r }
```

Comment: @ArupRakshit it means that I need to change odd number lines

Comment: show us one expected output as an example..

Comment: What does it mean to feel an array?

Comment: Note the answers you have been given so far are not 2d arrays, but arrays of arrays. There are a few practical differences. Arrays of arrays are probably more idiomatic structures in Ruby, and perfectly adequate for your current task. However, if you are taking numerical puzzles from Pascal and replicating in Ruby, you may prefer to use something like the `narray` gem which does implement multidimensional arrays for Ruby.

Comment: I would recommend you try learning some of the syntax before you try jumping right into a problem like this.  Asking for the answer to this problem will not help you learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accept simplicity. 
Use `matrix` class in Ruby.

```
require 'matrix'
m = 3
n = 4
#considering 1-indexed array/matrices and reversing even/odd conditions
Matrix.build(m, n) do |r, c|
  r.even? ? (m > c ? c+1 : 0) : m - c
  # if r.even? and m > c
  #   c+1
  # elsif r.even? 
  #   0
  # else
  #   m-c
  # end
end
#=> Matrix[[1, 2, 3, 0], [3, 2, 1, 0], [1, 2, 3, 0]]
```

Here, whenever n > m, those cells will retain the default value, which is 0 in this case.
Commented the alternative implementation of ternary operation with `if/else`.